# i want to move text up (repeatdly) using javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

i want to move text up (repeatedly)  using java-script ??

i want to move the last topics (for example) up (repeatedly) in Vertically way ..

how could i do that???

Regards,
Buffon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't you just change the top value in css using a timeout? or do you want transitions?

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $('#element').css({'top': '50px'});             
},1000);
```

1000 = 1s